# What is this icon in my status bar that looks like a finger pointing at 3 horizontal lines?

Tags: notification-icons, 8.1-oreo

Can anyone identify this icon?

[image: Screenshot]

here again with context:

[image]

I can't find anything online and no one at Verizon or Kyocera can identify it either. I need help figuring out what this icon is and what it means.

I have contacted the Verizon Tech's, Kyocera and personally searched online, with no positive ID. Deleted all apps, factory reset, and even safe mode start up, and the icon remains at the top of the screen in the status bar. The only time the icon is not at the top of the screen is when you click on the drop down for the status bar icons. This phone is the newest Kyocera Duraforce Pro-2. Glove mode nor the underwater camera mode have any affect on the icon when switching these two selections on or off.

Any information on what this is would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mailed Kyocera linking this question and they replied very quickly.

**It is a Verizon security app** and Kyocera can't do a thing about it. Mail extract :

> Allow us to inform you that this Icon is for a Verizon security application running on the phone, please be aware that this will not affecting its functionality. At the moment there is no way to remove the Icon.

Screenshot of mail below. You would need to chase Verizon for more details as to what it does but being a device tied with them, I guess you have to live with it.

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

You can refer to the Tech Support Case Number: 00689640
 and follow up with Kyocera (Phone.Help@kyocera.com) 
 if you wish (The person who sent the email is Karla H, Technical Support Specialist).

Answer (score 0):

Go into accessibility and turn off the "security and privacy" app and the icon will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I went into accessibility and turned off "Digital Secure" and the icon went away.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, apps and notifications, and then down to digital secure or safety and security and click on it. Then turn off all notifications and force stop it. The symbol should go away.

Comment: But have you told us What It Is, and the ramifications of shutting it off? It may be under Security for a reason. Just turning off a fire alarm doesn't shield you from fire.